# Regex to accept only 2 places after 

Tags: c#, regex

Hi all i need all these possible cases to be valid

```
123
123.1
123.12
```

I tried this `^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$ or ^[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]$` but does not works can any one help me out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Based on your second example, but allows either one or two decimal places, and makes the whole decimal part optional.

[EDIT]

OP has altered the criteria of the question -- see comments below. He now wants digits prior to the decimal point to only allow up to six digits and has asked me to edit the answer to suit.

All that is needed is to replace the `*` (for any number of digits) with `{0,6}` (for between zero and six digits). If you wanted at least one digit, then it would be `{1,6}`.

Here is the modified regex:

```
^[0-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: I suggest making the second part non-capturing, but that is just preference I suppose.

Comment: @Spudely : SOrry this is working fime i need another help my digits before should be minimum 1 and max 6 so can u edit and give

Comment: @user - is that all your digits, or just the decimal ones? or...? please clarify and I'll edit the answer to suit.

Comment: @Spudely digits before the decimals like `123456.12` but it should not be limited even if i enter `12343.12` also it has to be valid and if some thing like `3456765.12` this must be invalid

Comment: @user - okay, I've edited the answer. Hope I've understood your change in criteria okay.

Comment: SPudely numbers before can be acceptable from `0-9` but a max of 6 digits should be allowed before .

Comment: @user - okay, I didn't understand it properly (I did think the 0-6 thing was a bit weird!). I'll edit again.....

Answer (score 5):

try ...

```
^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

*** Edited** as suggested to make it non-capturing.

Answer (score 2):

almost got it...

`^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: hmm, not quite: this allows a trailing dot without decimals - eg `123.`

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to worry about figures that start with a dot, treat the dot without any numbers as invalid, and reject empty numbers:

```
^(?:\d+|\d*\.\d{1,2})$
```

This accepts `1`, `.1`, `1.0` but rejects `.`, `1.`, and (empty number).

Answer (score 1):

Try this as per all your requirements

```
 ^(\d{0,6})(\.\d{1,2})?$
```