# RegExp Place zero(0) after three decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

**`Hi all i need all these possible cases to be valid`**

```
0.001
0.320
0.009
0.0
0.3
0.9
```

let reqDecimal=/^(0(.\d+)?|1(.0+)?)$/;
I tried above code need to expected 3 decimal values not more than.

Comment: Try test it on https://regexr.com/ online regex tester.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978351/regex-to-accept-only-2-places-after link too.

Comment: @sameer: Can you also add some invalid samples so we know what should not match? For your given data you can simply use `^\d+\.\d{1,3}$`

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace both of your plus signs with `{1,3)`:

```
/^(0(.\d{1,3})?|1(.0{1,3})?)$/
```

This ensures that there are between 1 and 3 digits between each decimal:

```js
const regex = /^(0(.\d{1,3})?|1(.0{1,3})?)$/;
const amounts = [
  "0.001",
  "0.320",
  "0.009",
  "0.0",
  "0.3",
  "0.9",
  "0.",
  "0.0000",
  "1.",
  "1.000",
  "1.0000"
]

amounts.forEach(function(amount) {
  console.log(amount, "=", regex.test(amount));
});
```

This can also be seen working on Regex101 **[here](https://regex101.com/r/sayxE9/2/)**.

Comment: I assume this is being used for some sort of percentage system stored in decimals (where `1.000` would be the highest acceptable value - corresponding to `100%`), though if it is required to have `1.xxx` you can simply replace the `.0` with `.\d` as `/^(0(.\d{1,3})?|1(.\d{1,3})?)$/` :)

Comment: Could be, it's totally unclear what the OP wants now that you say that.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use:

```
^(?:1|0)\.\d{1,3}$
```

If you are wanting to stay at or under `1.000`:

```
^0\.\d{1,3}\b|1\.0{1,3}\b$
```

**Examples**:

https://regex101.com/r/wKZseY/1
https://regex101.com/r/wKZseY/2